# Gitlabs upgrade: getting 500 error on certain pages

Tags: git, unicorn, gitlab

I am getting 500 errors on certain pages. Here are a few examples: /u/root, /merge_requests?assignee_id=&label_name=&milestone_id=&scope=created-by-me&sort=newest&state=closed, /admin

**UPDATE**

Here is a picture of both of the table columns:
http://imageupper.com/gi/?galID=S0200010053W139568325644090&n=1&m=1

**UPDATE**
I've gone into the logs and found this for one of the views that I am getting 500 error for:

```
Started GET "/admin" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-24 14:26:02 -0400
Processing by Admin::DashboardController#index as HTML
  Rendered admin/dashboard/index.html.haml within layouts/admin (16.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass):
    36:       %hr
    37:       - @projects.each do |project|
    38:         %p
    39:           = link_to project.name_with_namespace, [:admin, project], class: 'str-truncated'
    40:           %span.light.pull-right
    41:             #{time_ago_with_tooltip(project.created_at)}
    42:
  app/models/project.rb:250:in `to_param'
  app/views/admin/dashboard/index.html.haml:39:in `block in _app_views_admin_dashboard_index_html_haml__4544594                                                                                                                                                                248014738902_70143663654700'
  app/views/admin/dashboard/index.html.haml:37:in `_app_views_admin_dashboard_index_html_haml__4544594248014738                                                                                                                                                                902_70143663654700'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:58:in `set_current_user_for_thread'
```

Comment: Did you import data from an old installation?

Comment: I actually just followed the upgrade process. This was not a new install. So all of the old data is currently there, but I did not have to import it.

Comment: if you go into mysql for the production database what does "show columns from merge_requests;" say? also "show columns from issues;"?

Comment: I've added a link to a picture of what you asked for to the original question.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Long day at work. Those columns in your image correct. The error you posted says it can't find the `path` method. There are only two tables with `path` as a column: `namespaces` and `projects`. What are you upgrading from? Is it from a version before global namespaces were deprecated?

Comment: Yes. It was from version 5.4 I believe. I do get a warning to remove one of my public projects or move it to a different namespace, but i am not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: that might be the issue, then. `select name, path, namespace_id from projects;` and `select path from namespaces;` should have no NULL values.

Comment: Yeah looks like I have a null for the depreciated global namespace, should I just remove that record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `NULL` for the path in the `namespaces` table, don't delete it. There are probably projects referencing it's `id`. 
Give `path` a value you're comfortable with. We just put our company name in ours when we did the switch. 
Something like:

`update namespaces set path = 'sixfoot' where path is null;`

That might solve your problem.

If there are `NULL` values in the projects table for the `namespace_id`, then create a namespace in GitLab, then `update projects set namespace_id={id the new namespace};`.

That may not solve all your upgrade issues, but it should get the links in the views rendering again without a 500.